# Force Internet Explorer to read POST message without downloading it

Tags: web-services, http-headers

I have a scenario in which a client application sends a POST request to an asp.net page to which the page responds with a json string which I need to consume on the client side.
However, Internet explorer is trying to download the *.aspx page, containing the json string.

What HTTP headers must the response contain to disable the download in Internet Explorer?

Currently, the response HTTP headers are:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-File-Name,X-File-Type,X-File-Size
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private,private, no-cache
Content-Length:1050
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 12 Jul 2013 08:24:24 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=qjudp3nct3czltyvc4yxpiri; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are consuming that web service.

If you are consuming it from inside a web page using jQuery, it shouldn't be a problem, Internet Explorer won't force download the file.

If you access the file directly after the POST (redirect to the URL that serves the JSON) and you want to display the JSON as plain text, you must set the Content-Type to text/plain; charset=utf-8